# Switchboard assignment to undeclared variable error

Tags: solana-program

I am building a coin flip app and decided to use switchboard oracle to provide vrf randomness on-chain. Firstly, users need to initialize a vrf account to successfully communicate with oracle. I am really struggling to do that because I want users to sign transactions using their wallets. So I end up providing switchboard idl into my app, and now I am trying to call vrfInit method. I am getting "assignment to undeclared variable" error.

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import styles from './styles.module.scss'
import { 
  useConnection, 
  useAnchorWallet
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID }from '@solana/spl-token';
import * as sbv2 from "@switchboard-xyz/switchboard-v2";
import * as anchor from '@project-serum/anchor' 

import switchboardV2IDL from '../switchboard_v2_devnet.json';
import programIDL from '../program_idl.json';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  // my devnet program id
  const PROGRAM_ID = "BPRwf1iEMy6v22JTGQTQBRBoVXZNETusmNjWNNadyj1F"

  const { connection } = useConnection()
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
  const cluster = "devnet"
  
  async function initUser() {
    if (!wallet) return
    const provider = new anchor.AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {"preflightCommitment": "processed"})

    // getting switchboard program id
    const programId = sbv2.getSwitchboardPid(cluster);

    // setting type for switchboard and program idl
    const switchboardAnchorIdl = switchboardV2IDL as anchor.Idl
    const programIdl = programIDL as anchor.Idl

    // creating switchboard program instance
    const switchboardProgram = new anchor.Program(switchboardAnchorIdl, programId, provider)

    const vrfKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

    const [vrfClientKey, vrfClientBump] = anchor.utils.publicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("CLIENTSEED"), vrfKeypair.publicKey.toBytes()],
      new PublicKey(PROGRAM_ID)
  );

    // getting switchboard GLOBAL program state
    //@ts-ignore
    const [programStateAccount, stateBump] = sbv2.ProgramStateAccount.fromSeed(switchboardProgram);
    
    const callback = {
      programId: PROGRAM_ID,
      accounts: [
        { pubkey: vrfClientKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
        { pubkey: vrfKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}
      ],
      ixData: new anchor.BorshInstructionCoder(programIdl).encode(
        "consumeRandomness",
        ""
      ),
    }

    // oracle queue address DEVNET
    const queueKey = new PublicKey('F8ce7MsckeZAbAGmxjJNetxYXQa9mKr9nnrC3qKubyYy')

    // temporary escrow account
    const escrow = new PublicKey("FQyfVZnqZadoSAiGRXHDoWEgHcBYLawDWE64wWZ7cFAB")

    try {

      await switchboardProgram.methods
      .vrfInit({
        stateBump,
        callback,
      })  
      .accounts({
        vrf: vrfKeypair.publicKey,
        escrow,
        authority: vrfClientKey,
        oracleQueue: queueKey,
        programState: programStateAccount.publicKey,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .preInstructions([
        anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
          fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
          newAccountPubkey: vrfKeypair.publicKey,
          space: 29058,
          lamports:
            await provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
              29058
            ),
          programId: programId,
        }),
      ])
      .signers([vrfKeypair])
      .rpc();
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
      
    }
  } 


  return (
    <div className={styles.homePage}>
      <button onClick={initUser} className={styles.initButton}>Init User</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

[image]